# SXA's Local "Data" datasource folder not displayed in the Content Editor for content editors

Tags: sxa

Some how, the local "Data" folder (the one from SXA), underneath a page, is not displayed for content editors in the Content Editor:

[image: Screenshot from content editors perspective]

While an admin is able to see it in the Content Editor:
[image: Screenshot from admin perspective]

According to the access viewer the content editor should be able to see it:
[image]

Is this a "feature" of the SXA local "Data" folder, to prevent users from editing it in the content editor because they should use the Experience Editor?

Comment: is `Data` folder marked as hidden? Can you check for the other users in the "view" ribbon tab, if "show hidden items" is checked?

Comment: Agreed. The `Data` folder is likely hidden, this would be best practice.

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak! The folder was hidden indeed. And although it could be best practice, I disabled the "hidden" checkbox on the standard values item for the Data template for now.

Comment: @ArjenvanVeen I'm glad I helped. Comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The local `Data` folder in SXA is usually hidden.

Check for the other users in the `View` ribbon tab, if `Hidden items` checkbox is checked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While trying to configure security for the users of our system, I found that I needed to grant access to the template used for the *Data* item; which I believe is a *Virtual Page Data*.

**Example:** The following applies security changes to the Data folders.

```
# This is a helper method to simplify the changes.
function New-AccessRuleList {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType("System.Collections.Generic.List[Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule]")]
    param(
        [string]$Identity,
        [string[]]$AccessRule,
        [Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.PropagationType]$PropagationType,
        [Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.SecurityPermission]$SecurityPermission
    )

    $list = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule]"
    foreach($rule in $accessrule) {
        $list.Add((New-ItemAcl -Identity $Identity -AccessRight $rule -PropagationType $PropagationType -SecurityPermission $SecurityPermission))
    }

    @(,$list)
}

$allowItemProps = @{
    PropagationType = [Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.PropagationType]::Entity
    SecurityPermission = [Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.SecurityPermission]::AllowAccess
}

$realEveryone = "\Everyone"
$virtualDataItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{9700DC24-8969-4638-ACC3-34D54335829E}"
$accessRules = New-Object Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRuleCollection
$accessRules.AddRange((New-AccessRuleList -Identity $realEveryone -AccessRule item:create @allowItemProps))
$virtualDataItem | Add-ItemAcl -AccessRules $accessRules
```

The final results:

[image: Security Settings On Item]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Michael, but it had nothing to do with access rights. The item was just hidden because the "hidden" checkbox was checked in the standard values item for the Data template.